# Can't find range error using script with third-part API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-drive-api

It's my first time trying to use google apps scripts, using it on google sheets to try and collect data from TSM ( Tradeskill Master ) a wow third part service, to filter and fill a section of spreadsheet.

I already managed how to get the authentication with the API, based on the example they provided on their, which can be found here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f2_wAa4K8FYO-PvijgwViCMBx2-8xf_BOOokcbAtGvg/edit#gid=2037386834

The documentation for the API can be found here:

https://blog.tradeskillmaster.com/new-public-web-api/

My issue is the following

I'm trying to read the data they provide through the API and filter it, since I need just a couple hundred entries from what is like tens of thousands, I tried the following code:

```
    function populateRealmData() 
    {
      var selectedRegion = getSelectionSheet().getRange(getRegionCellRange()).getValue();
      if (!selectedRegion) {
        throw new Error("No region selected");
      }
      
      var region = getRegions()
        .filter((region) => region.gameVersion == 'Wrath')
        .find((region) => region.name == selectedRegion);
      if (!region) {
        throw new Error("Invalid region selected");
      }
    
      var selectedAH = getSelectionSheet().getRange(getRealmCellRange()).getValue();
      if (!selectedAH) {
        throw new Error("No AH selected");
      }
      
      var ah = getAHs(region.id)
        .find((ah) => ah.realmName == selectedAH);
      if (!ah) {
        throw new Error("Invalid AH selected");
      }
    
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = getRegionPricingData(region.id).items;
      for(var id=16; id < 186; id++)
      {
         var SheetCellID = () => "C" + id
         var SheetCellMinBuyout = () => "D" + id
         var item = data.filter(x => x.itemid == getSelectionSheet().getRange(SheetCellID).getValue())
         sheet.getRange(SheetCellMinBuyout).setValue(Item.marketValue)    
      }  
    }
```

The error occurs on the second to last line, it can't find the range for SheetCellID, which should be something like C18 on the first pass of the loop. I have never used this script before, for what I understand it's similar to Javascript, I been trying to debug it to see what the value of SheetCellID but I don't understand how to inspect it, I don't understand how to do that on the debug window.

I'm sure it's something very silly that I'm doing wrong, but I been over it for a couple hours now and have no idea what it is.

Comment: Use the Google Apps Script debugger together with console.log to print to the executions log the value of SheetCellID as well other relevant variables. If you need further help, please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting . Then add a [mcve] (make a shorter code, add the textual error message, describe the spreadsheet structure and add some sample data).

Comment: Your example code has several undefined functions which make it impossible for us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thiago, it looks like `SheetCellID`and `SheetCellMinBuyout` are functions instead of range reference strings. Can you please try replacing the two lines for `SheetCellID` and `SheetCellMinBuyout` with the following:

```
var SheetCellID =  "C" + id
var SheetCellMinBuyout =  "D" + id
```

Also, you can output the values of these using console.log:

```
console.log(SheetCellID)
console.log(SheetCellMinBuyout)
```

If it works at this point, you don't need to do anything else. However, for completeness, you should also be able to use `SheetCellID()` and `SheetCellMinBuyout()` in the last two lines of the for loop and leave everything else the same, since they are functions:

```
for(var id=16; id < 186; id++){
  var SheetCellID = () => "C" + id
  var SheetCellMinBuyout = () => "D" + id
  var item = data.filter(x => x.itemid == getSelectionSheet().getRange( SheetCellID() ).getValue())
  sheet.getRange( SheetCellMinBuyout() ).setValue(Item.marketValue)    
}
```